# "Acknowledge over PGA limit" wait event in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle12c

We are seeing this wait event (with high CPU/slow performance) all over the place in AWR after upgrade from 11g to 12c. The documentation for this seems to be scarce and all I can gather is, when this wait event occurs:

1. The PGA size set by parameter PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT has been exceeded
2. Oracle will find sessions that use the highest PGA and terminate
   them abruptly

Above are what I found from blogs and not from the official docs. If anyone could confirm the above and elaborate further, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what did you set for pga_aggregate_target, is it similar to what you had before the migration?

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO: I have to check with DBA on that but I assume it was left the default value.

Comment: There are no default value, this parameter should be set in function of your database usage, number of concurrent users, type of application... maybe it is too low, because pga_aggregate_target can still grow up to 200% of what you set for pga_aggregate_targert